# Gauging the general health of Jenkins builds

Tags: hudson, jenkins

Does anyone know how to gauge the general health of all the jobs in a Jenkins  instance ?  E.g. A graph that shows the number of failures over time, sorta like the # tests graph provided by the Dashboard plugin.

Purpose: we have a common build framework that is used by the majority of our Jenkins builds.  When we make changes to the common framework, we'd like to quickly find failures that were introduced by the changes, but it's  hard to easily find "new" failures vs old failures that are unrelated to the framework change, especially since the "Last Builds" screen only shows maybe 30 jobs, and during a build storm that page will roll over pretty quickly, meaning that I can't find failures easily. I'd love to see a graph of our failures, I'd expect to see a steady state of failures. Then during a build framework change which causes failures, I would potentially see a huge spike in the number of failures, indicating that something systemic happened.

The best plugin I've found is the Plot plugin, but it's relatively undocumented and will take a while to integrate, so I was hoping someone already know how to detect this category of error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you seen the [Global Build Stats](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Global+Build+Stats+Plugin) plugin? I haven't tried it (yet) because I just found it, but it looks flexible enough to give you something useful if you configure it right.

Comment: I'm going to mark this as the accepted answer, but we actually had to uninstall the Global Build Stats plugin as it caused us some serious problems.   Our build slaves' executors were taking a very long time to come online following a master restart, and we isolated a probable root cause to locking contention on a single global build stats file that the plugin uses.

Answer (score 0):

We use [Dashboard View](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Dashboard+View), it gives you a per-view enhancement like Build Statistics and Job Statics which I think are what you are looking for.

Dashboard View offers a bunch of enhancements to the view page, consider playing around with it to suit your needs and ask if you have more questions.

Comment: Thanks, but we already use the Dashboard view - it doesn't show an aggregated status for all of the jobs in the system, just the most recent builds that happened to run.